# I have a passport stamp with the wrong date. What problems could this cause?

Tags: passports, passport-stamps

I'm a US citizen and I visited Montreal for nine days in April. I just looked at my passport and my entry stamp incorrectly has March for the month so it looks like my trip lasted from March 9 to April 16.

It looks like US citizens are allowed to stay in Canada for 180 days without a visa, so I'm not worried about looking like I took an illegal trip. I'm just wondering if having a stamp that doesn't match any other data on me (which I assume is correct) could cause issues.

Comment: I enter and exit Canada numerous times each year and only when I fly in is anything stamped in my passport, when driving nothing is ever stamped.  As your entry and exit abide by the rules regarding length of stay, you should have nothing to worry about, unless you entered another country during the time you were "in" Canada.

Comment: I can't recall anyone ever checking the dates tamped into my passport. They have computer records they look at.

Comment: If you are accused of a crime committed in Canada during the time you say you didn't stay there, with witnesses claiming they saw you, you might have a hard time claiming that you weren't in Canada at all.

Comment: @MastaBaba For things like this you can usually request extracts from immigration records.

Comment: @MastaBaba Sure. But on the other hand, if he committed a crime somewhere else, he now has a pretty solid alibi. :)

Comment: Nice thinking, @Nix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlikely.  If for some reason they were trying to use this as evidence of you being in the country, you could request your computer records (or show flights etc) to prove that it was merely an error with their stamps.  And they could verify this themselves from both the Canadian or American side if they had to.

Any visa application in the future where you *might* get asked when you were there, just put the true dates - if they check, they're going to be looking at computer records again, not the stamps in your passport.

From personal experience, the only time anyone has ever looked at dates on stamps was as you were leaving the country, to ensure you didn't overstay.  But they always defer to their own records, rather than the passport as a definitive source of information.